# Android: Trying to add setText to an EditText

Tags: android, xml, reverse-engineering, android-edittext

I'm just now dipping my toes into reverse engineering Android apps and I'm sure this is a very newbie question. I'm simply trying to automatically insert some text into an edittext field but I get an error during re-compiling in Virtuous Ten Studio.

Here's the original xml:

`<EditText android:textSize="16.0dip" android:textColor="@color/black" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/username_textfield" android:background="@color/transparent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:cursorVisible="true" android:singleLine="true" android:selectAllOnFocus="true" android:maxLength="99" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:textCursorDrawable="@null">`

All I do is I add: `android:setText="@string/login_username_filled"` to it so that it looks like this;

`<EditText android:textSize="16.0dip" android:textColor="@color/black" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@id/username_textfield" android:background="@color/transparent" android:setText="@string/login_username_filled" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:cursorVisible="true" android:singleLine="true" android:selectAllOnFocus="true" android:maxLength="99" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:textCursorDrawable="@null">`

And in the Strings.xml file I added:

`<string name="login_username_filled">foobar@gmail.com</string>
<string name="login_password_filled">foobar</string>`

And I get the error "no resource identifier found for attribute 'setText' in package 'android'. I've tried adding:

`<item type="id" name="login_username_filled">false</item>
<item type="id" name="login_password_filled">false</item>`

to ids.xml

and also adding:

`<public type="id" name="login_username_filled" id="0x7f050128" />
<public type="id" name="login_password_filled" id="0x7f050129" />`

to public.xml (I made up some hex numbers that incremented the last number in the type for those, so that the numbers didn't already exist), but I get public.xml errors there.

I know I'm missing something simple here, but I barely know java coding at all and very very little smali reversing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an "no resource identifier found" because there's no `android:setText` xml attribute for EditText. The correct attribute is `android:text`.

If you just want to set some text that will disappear when the user starts to type, follow IrishWhiskey's answer.

Comment: Aha! No wonder. I was basing the setText on [EditText Dox](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) but I suppose that's a method rather than a property, lol.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like a hint for the user in the EditText field? or actually putting a default text the user can use inside the EditText field?

For the hint you can do either one of these

java:

```
myTextView.setHint("My conditional hint");
```

xml:

```
android:hint="hint text"
```

or preferably

```
android:hint="@string/hint"
```

If you mean, enter some text on an `onClick` (as in button pressed) or some other condition please let me know and i'll try and help

Comment: Thanks, @Paulo Viana had my specific answer, but I'm sure I'll be using your answer at some point in the future as well. =)

Comment: @GeekDrop.com you're welcome, I'm glad you got the answer you needed.